# Passing parameters to a function

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I am new to JavaScript. I am learning it but I am not understanding the "function with parameters". Why a function require a "parameters" & how would we know that this function will require a "parameters". Can you provide me with a link where I can learn all the JavaScript from basic & I want a link where all small JavaScript programs with details are provided.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best resources to learn JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript)

Comment: I disagree. It's not an exact duplicate. @Suraj

Answer (score 2):

A function would require parameters if its output is based on some input values. For instance, if you were going to write a function that adds two numbers together:

```
function adder(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

I know that this function takes two parameters named `a` and `b` because I can see it in the definition after the function name: `adder(a, b)`. I need to "pass" two numbers to this function for it to produce good output, like so:

```
adder(2, 3); // returns 5
```

If I don't pass it two numbers, the returned result will be `NaN`, because the function's arguments will be `undefined`:

```
adder(); // a = undefined, b = undefined, returns NaN
adder(7); // a = 7, b = undefined, returns NaN
```

For more information on learning Javascript, one place to go is the [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).

Answer (score 1):

A function does not **require** paremeters. All functions are made of 2 essentials parts:

- **The Implementation** - Which is the actual code of the function, what it does.
- **The Interface** - The things that connect it to the "outside world" aka, the rest of the program.

Parameters are part of the **interface**, you can pass parameters to your function in order to help it achieve its goal towards the overall program.

---

Consider the following (theoretical) example:

Let's say I want to make a TV operation program. I want to define a way to switch channels.

```
function switchChannel() { /* do some stuff */ }
```

However, what would be the first thing that you would ask yourself? What channel does the user want to change to? **That's the interface problem**, so in order to include that in our function, we would do something like this:

```
function switchChannel(channelNum) { /* do some stuff */ }
```

When I call the function, I will most likely do it like so:

```
switchChannel(24);
```

That 24 *value* will be passed to the `channelNum` *parameter* inside of the `switchChannel()` *function*.

So the complete example code:

```
function switchChannel(channelNum) { alert(channelNum); }
switchChannel(24);
```

The result would be an alert with **24**

---

That's the gist of it, hope it was helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to view this page http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp.

And I will add few words in my way.

For example we want to change background color of the page

for that I will create function like this

```
function changeBG(whichColor){
document.bgColor = whichColor;
}
```

So, I can call the function from button click (Red button) -- `onclick="changeBG('red');"`
same and I can call that method with diff parameter (for example `onclick="changeBG('green');"`
we can reuse the same code, when we need it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to javascript.

All programming languages have functions which require parameters.

Actually, **all functions have parameters**. A function is just like you learn about in math class: you give it an input value, and it gives you an output value.

**A function with "no parameters" actually has 0 parameters.** By its nature, it can only return one value (unless it's accessing external variables, which is very poor form).

For example:

```
function sum0() {            // <-- "no" parameters/arguments
    return 0;
}
function sum1(x0) {          // <-- 1 parameters/arguments
    return x0;
}
function sum2(x0, x1) {      // <-- 2 parameters/arguments
    return x0+x1;
}
function sum3(x0, x1, x2) {  // <-- 3 parameters/arguments
    return x0+x1+x2
}
```

(Of course you would never write these functions; they're terrible and repetitive. The entire reason we write functions it to avoid having to repeat things. To actually implement a sum function, you'd either pass in an array as a single argument, or do `return arguments.reduce(sum2)`)

A function which has no parameters is sometimes called a "thunk", because it doesn't need to process new information. It's "already thought-out". For example:

```
function firstNPrimes(n) {    // 1 parameter, not "thought out"
    // sieve of Eratosthanes goes here
}
```

Say we now wanted a function `firstFivePrimes`. We have many ways we could do so:

```
function firstFivePrimes() {   // no parameters, already "thought out"
    return firstNPrimes(5);
}
```

However it's already "thought-out", so we could just pre-calculate it, or calculate it in the background:

```
function firstFivePrimes() {   // no parameters, already "thought out"
    return [2,3,5,7,11];
}
```

The two implementations are identical, assuming you are not accessing global variables (poor form).

Here's a "thunk" which always returns the same value: a function!

```
function makeCounter() {
    var i = 0;
    return function() {
        console.log(i++);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
> counter = makeCounter()
> counter()
0
> counter()
1
> counter()
2
> anotherCounter = makeCounter()
> anotherCounter()
0
> anotherCounter()
1
> counter()
3
> anotherCounter()
2
```